# Why data.table is taking too much time to execute a specific part of script in r (Reproducible Example given)?

Tags: r, function, datetime, data.table

I am having some issues with extremely slow processing of few lines of my script as given below .I guess apply & customised function are slowing down the performance
Any suggestions to expedite this script/calculation ??

### One can use these tables and check the code

```
dt1=data.table(location_id=rep("abc",52),report_date=c(rep("2020-04-22",24),rep("2020-04-23",24),rep("2020-04-24",4)),hour=c(rep(c(0:23),2),0,1,2,3),hr_visitors=c(20:67,345,236,123,67))


dt2=dt1[, date_hour := as.POSIXct(paste0(report_date,hour), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")]
```

### Part 1

Creating timestamp column using date and hour observations

```
Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:22:55 GMT"

dt2=copy(dt1)[, date_hour := as.POSIXct(paste0(report_date,hour), 
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")]

Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:31:51 GMT"
```

### Part 2

Applying function model on a bigger data set

```
stl_model_outlier<-function(xyz){
model=ts(xyz,frequency=24)
f=stl(model,"periodic",robust = TRUE)
result=data.table(row_id=which(f$weights<1e-8))%>%mutate(outlier="Yes")
return(list(result))
}

Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:41:51 GMT"

results1<-dt2[,lapply(.SD, stp_model_outlier), by = location_id, .SDcols = "hr_visitors"]

Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:54:51 GMT"
```

Comment: Would be easier to understand if you provided a reproducible data example, and adopted a cleaner style for your code (indentation, space after comma, etc.)

Comment: I have provided a reproducible data example ...thanks

Comment: Please test your code, I believe you are missing a close-bracket after `as.POSIXct(...)`. And ... `.SDcols=c(1:2,5:10)` refers to more columns than present in `dt1`. (Reproducible this is *not*.)

Comment: Why are you mixing `data.table` and `dplyr`? If you're using `data.table` for speed or memory reasons, then using `mutate` negates that fairly quickly. That's not to say that `mutate` is slow, but ... it defeats the modify-in-place semantics of `data.table`, incurring more data-copy than needed (per the `data.table` methods).

Comment: dt2 contains all 4 important columns that would be enough to run the script , since my data had some irrelevant columns  ,hence .SDcols=c(1:2,5:10)... Btw I have removed that part ...... Function does not take even a second to execute , so main problem thats slowing down the script is usage of lapply + function inside data.table  Code works , but takes a lot of time .....For Part1 ,may be as.POSIXct slows script